# How can i know the particular HAL versions required for particular Android Release

Tags: android, android-source, hal

Let's say i am working with Android 13 version, how can i know the HAL versions that has to be in my code(Android 13). Is there any limitation that, this particular android release(Android 13 in my case) should contain these particular HAL versions?
Let's say Treble is enabled in my code, and my current version is Android 13, because of treble is enabled in my code i will update to next android version easily. So my another question here is, in my current code(android 13) i am using one HAL let's assume radio hal version 2.0, how can i know whether the radio HAL 2.0 is supported or deprecated in the next Android release(Android 14)?

I checked the official google page, https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/hal but it didn't answer my questions.